# how to pass a variable into a function connected to a button pyqt5 python

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
def open_browser(i):
            print("open")

 for i in range(5):
     new_name_label = 'name_label'+str(i)
     list_names.append(new_name_label)
     setattr(self, list_names[i], QPushButton(str(ordered_names[i]),self))
     exec(f'self.name_label{i}.setGeometry(250,{y_axis_name},340,110)')
     exec(f'self.name_label{i}.clicked.connect(open_browser({i}))')
     y_axis_name= y_axis_name + 110
```

"i" is a variable and I cant find a way to click the button self.name_label and then connect that to a function and pass in the variable "i". when i attempted to run it I get the error

[image: image of error]

it seems that the variable "i" is not being replaced by one of the numbers in the range represented by "i" and instead i the letter is trying to be passed in.

Comment: Why are you using `exec`?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: `self.name_label` is not `Button` but normal `string` - you can't click it`

Comment: if you want many buttons then use list `self.name_label = []` instead variables `name_label1`, `name_label2` - and use `append()` to add buttons to list. It doesn't need to use `exec()` and it will be more useful then separated variables

Comment: for sure you can't use `connect(open_browser(i))` because it will first run `result = open_browser(i)` and next `connect(result)` so it tries to connect `button` with `result`, not with function `open_browser(i)`

Comment: if you want to assign with argument then you could use `lambda` to create function without argument `connect( lambda:open_browser(i) )` but when you run it in `for`-loop then it may need `connect( lambda x=i:open_browser(x) )`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign function with argument then you can use `lambda` to create function without argument

```
connect( lambda:open_browser(i) )
```

but if you run it in loop then you may need also to copy value `i` to new variable.

```
connect( lambda x=i:open_browser(x) )
```

If you use directly `i` then all buttons will use reference to variable `i`, not values from `i` - and finally all buttons will get the same value - last value assigned to `i` in loop.

---

Code `connect(open_browser(i))` works as

```
result = open_browser(i) 
connect(result)
```

and because `def open_browser()` doesn't use `return` so it automatically runs `return None` and your code works like

```
result = None
connect(result)
```

and you have

```
connect(None)
```

and later error shows `Unexpected type "NoneType"`

---

**BTW:**

If you use `for`-loop to create objects then better use `list` to keep these objects. It doesn't need `exec()` and it can be more useful later - because later you can use again `for`-loop to check all objects from list.

Besides it looks very strange when someone need `exec()` to create code.

```
self.buttons = []

for i in range(5):
     b = QPushButton(str(ordered_names[i]), self)
     b.setGeometry(250, y_axis_name, 340, 110)
     b.clicked.connect( lambda x=i:open_browser(x) )

     self.buttons.append( b )

     y_axis_name += 110
```